# Makefile multiline dash command run executable in a detached process

Tags: bash, makefile, dash-shell

I have the following target in my makefile: (I'd like to run python http server in a detached process and when bash script is done kill the server)

```
TEST_PORT = 17777
test::
    $(ENV_VARS) \
    python -m SimpleHTTPServer $(TEST_PORT); \
    PID=$$(lsof -t -i @localhost:$(TEST_PORT) -sTCP:listen); \
    echo $(PID); \
    if [ -n "$$PID" ]; \
    then \
        python test.py; \
    fi; \
    function finish { \
        if [ -n "$$PID" ]; \
        then \
            kill -9 $$PID; \
        fi \
    } \
    trap finish EXIT;
```

However when I put a `&` after the line `python ...` I get an error

> /bin/dash: Syntax error: ";" unexpected

How can this be done in a proper way?

## EDIT

I have changed my makefile to do the following:

```
test::
    python -m SimpleHTTPServer $(TEST_PORT) &
    PID=$$(lsof -t -i @localhost:$(TEST_PORT) -sTCP:listen); \
        if [ -n "$$PID" ]; \
        then \
            $(ENV_VARS) python test.py; \
        fi \
        function finish { \
            if [ -n "$$PID" ]; \
            then \
                kill -9 $$PID; \
            fi \
        } \
        echo $$PID; \
        trap finish EXIT;
```

However I am getting an error: (without the line number)

> /bin/dash: Syntax error: word unexpected

Comment: Do you get the same error when you omit the `python ...` line entirely? (In future you should try to prepare minimal examples-- I'm not going to mess around with python and ports just to reproduce your error.)

Comment: thanks, I will take it into account. I definitely needed a combination of `if`, `function` and the python command to demonstrate what is going on though (and not miss details)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The important thing to remember here is that your line breaks don't actually exist when the shell sees the command.

So your first command becomes:

```
$(ENV_VARS) python -m SimpleHTTPServer $(TEST_PORT); PID=$$(lsof -t -i @localhost:$(TEST_PORT) -sTCP:listen); echo $(PID); if [ -n "$$PID" ]; then python test.py; fi; function finish { if [ -n "$$PID" ]; then kill -9 $$PID; fi } trap finish EXIT;
```

And your second command becomes:

```
PID=$$(lsof -t -i @localhost:$(TEST_PORT) -sTCP:listen); if [ -n "$$PID" ]; then $(ENV_VARS) python test.py; fi function finish { if [ -n "$$PID" ]; then kill -9 $$PID; fi } echo $$PID; trap finish EXIT;
```

Now those are both very hard to read so I don't expect you to spot the problem but the problem is that you are missing statement terminators in a few places.

Specifically:

- Braces (`{}`) are word elements and so need spaces around them (and a terminator before, and after, the closing brace). You are missing those terminators here `fi } trap` and here `fi } echo`.
- `fi` is also not a statement terminator and so it needs one between it and the next statement. You are missing one here `test.py; fi function` (as well as the ones in the braces from the first point).